# Obtener datos de jtable

Tags: java, netbeans, jtable

Lo que intento hacer es algo complejo, primero lo que tengo es una tabla que se esta llenando con 3 valores cada vez que presiono un botón, entonces lo que quiero lograr es que al presionar otro botón pueda obtener todos los datos de la tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando aprieto agregar producto toma un ingrediente del combobox rescata el valor del txtfield y el valor del ultimo combobox, se agregan a la tabla según su clasificación.
Según la imagen lo que quiero lograr es que al apretar el botón siguiente pueda rescatar todos los valores de la tabla y guardarlos en la base de datos que tengo.

Comment: Muéstrenos con código lo que intentó.

Comment: un poco de codigo seria de ayuda para poder ayudarte
Saludos!!